# NSData --> Json --> NSArray and show information in Uitableview

Tags: json, ios6, nsarray, nsdata

I have a URL request, which  return a JSON String in this format:

```
    {
"code": 1, "data": [
{
"city": "Trier",
"distance": 6,
"id": "1",
"image": "1_51af0b6a7ce86.png", "lat": "49.750893",
"long": "6.622419",
"name": "A1 Trier",
"street": "Über Brücken 4",
"zip": "54294"
}, {
} ]
}
"city": "Trier",
    "distance": 7,
    "id": "2",
    "image": "nologo.png", "lat": "49.757984",
    "long": "6.640876", "name": "Safari Haus Trier", "street": "Stockplatz 2a", "zip": "54294"
```

Now I need a `NSData` and then a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to save this information,right?. I want to show the data from the JSON in a tableview. In each cell should be the name, place and distance from the club. How can I do this? in the first cell should be the first club and the name and so on.. and in the second cell the second club.

How can I split this JSON string?

Comment: create JSON object of the string and retrieve array of "Data" key. then save that array object one by one in to mutabledictionary with unique data identifier and get that data in tableviewforcell data.

Comment: can you post me an example please? because i am really new in json and nsdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link:

[Parsing JSON in Objective-C using NSJSONSerialization](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/03/06/parsing-json-in-objective-c-using-nsjsonserialization/)

As mentioned in the above link,  you can parse JSON using NSJSONSerialization as follows:

**STEP-1:** Convert your JSON String (say jsonString) to NSData

```
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**STEP-2:** Serializing JSON into data of NSArray

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

**STEP-3:** In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` tableview delegate method, create a custom cell for tableview where in you have three labels for displaying club name (say `lblName`), club distance (say `lblDistance`) and club place (say `lblPlace`). Once you are done with this, you can just manipulate data from array and display it in tableview

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: i have done it like you, but the app crash. I get the error [__NSDictionaryM dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa140d90
. the error happens in step 1. this is my code                                  NSData* data = [jsonstringgetclubs dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: i found the mistake. it should be an Nsdictionary not an array. But know i can only read the "data". I can not show only the distance for example. Only the hole block of informations

Comment: i got it. I do it by this way and now it works.                            NSLog(@"res %@",[[[responseArray objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"city"]);

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON kit for JSON parsing.

You can find JSONKit [here](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

and see this [example](http://www.14oranges.com/2011/08/how-to-use-jsonkit-for-ios-and-the-rotten-tomatoes-api/)

Comment: i need their an account and key. is it not possible without a json kit? and only with the functions of iOS 6?

Comment: that's just example. try using your json string parsing. using jsonkit functions.